# How to close one canvas in java swing, and replace with another one, without opening new window?

Tags: java, swing

So, for a project I'm currently working on, I'm creating a Mario-like game, with three different levels. I have finished level one so far, and have run into a problem I can't seem to figure out. When I am done the level (I have this door that the player runs into), level one is supposed to close and go back to the main class, which I called BaseClass, and then the BaseClass is supposed to open level 2.
However, instead of doing that, the program opens a new window on top of the old one, with the new level. I believe this might have something to do with the fact that I refer back to BaseClass by creating a new window with the new level. This new window is also a mixture of the two and is repeatedly flashing between yellow and green (the two background colours I have placed temporarily to differentiate between the two levels).
Is there a way for me to close one canvas, and open the other one, without having that problem? Also, the project is for a school course, and we are not allowed to use any non-basic Java libraries.

I have tried using JFrame closing, using a method that I found that involved the Principal class from the java.security package. I have also tried several random things, none of which seem to work.

Here is my BaseClass code for both the constructor and the method that is supposed to change the level.

```
int currentLevel = 1;

public BaseClass() {
    super("Epic Math Sprint");
    start();
    currentLevel++;
    this.setSize(800, 600);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);

}

public void start() {
    LevelOne firstLevel = new LevelOne();
    LevelTwo secondLevel = new LevelTwo();
    LevelThree thirdLevel = new LevelThree();
    switch (currentLevel) {
        case 1:
            this.add(firstLevel);
            break;
        case 2:
            this.remove(firstLevel);
            this.add(secondLevel);
            break;
        case 3:
            this.remove(secondLevel);
            this.add(thirdLevel);
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is the code I have in the actionPerformed method that checks whether the player is at the door, and if the door is open (drawPaper is false), and at that stage, changes the level. BTW, if you have any tips on how to check whether the player is on top of the door in a better way, please let me know.

```
if (!drawPaper && (xPos >= 575 && xPos <= 625 && yPos >= 150 && yPos <= 280) && !reachedGoal) {
        BaseClass main = new BaseClass();
        main.currentLevel = 2;
        main.start();
        reachedGoal = true;
    }
```

The reachedGoal is to prevent the program from continuously opening new windows every 5 milliseconds (what my timer is set to).

Comment: The “basic” concept is to start with a “base” container, this is then used to remove/add other components to. This “base” container is then add to what ever window you want. The point is to seperate your “container management” from your window, which should make it easier. You may also find that you need to call revalidate and repaint on your “base” container when you change components. You might also be able to use a CardLayout if you components are swing based

Comment: So, I would have say a main class, which creates a canvas/container. And that container has the levels? So when I change level, I update the container?

Comment: Basically, yes...

Comment: Once you have the basics sorted, I'd recommend using a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556) to actually swap the panels.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I followed the CardLayout method, and the problem I am experiencing now is that the graphics don't get shown. I added a System.out.println in my logic to see if it does get executed, and the correct thing was outputted. But nothing shows up on the screen.

Comment: *"..the problem I am experiencing now.."* ..is best handled on a **new** appropriately titled question with a [mcve]. Given the form of code required, 1st check if the problem can be reproduced ***without*** a card layout.